# Google Chrome Service Worker Persistent Storage Caching System

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, cache, google-chrome, browser-storage

[Moving](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration) from Google Chrome Extensions’ [Manifest V2](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2) to [Manifest V3,](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro) **service workers** replace background pages. [Background pages](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/background_pages) can be configured to be [persistent,](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/background_pages#manifest) but service workers can’t be [persistent.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67900978/4356188) Service workers get automatically terminated at times of inactivity, [and their variables are hence lost.](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/migrating_to_service_workers/#state)

Google’s documentation says [to use Storage APIs for persisting state.](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/migrating_to_service_workers/#state)

> If we port this code directly to MV3, requiring service workers, it's possible that the code will be terminated between when the name is set and the user clicks the browser action. If this happens, the set name will have been lost—and savedName will again be undefined.
>
> We can fix this bug by treating the Storage APIs as our source of truth:

As the extension I developed retrieves persistent variables [frequently,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70401067/how-do-you-call-a-function-every-second-in-a-chrome-extension-manifest-v3-backgr) I coded a variable caching system that uses values stored in memory and reads from `chrome.storage.local` only if the needed variables are undefined because the service worker was terminated.

Here’s the code. The `pull` function retrieves a variable from a supplied cache object if possible and otherwise reads from `chrome.storage.local`. The `push` function writes to a supplied cache object and writes to `chrome.storage.local`. The `useVariables` function makes it easy to “use” multiple variables with `Promise`s.

```
function pull(cache, key, defaultVal=undefined) {
  return (new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let fetched = cache[key];
    if (typeof fetched !== 'undefined') {
      resolve(fetched);
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  }))
  .catch(() => { // if the variable isn’t found in the cache
    let toGet = {};
    toGet[key] = defaultVal;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      chrome.storage.local.get(toGet, fetched => {
        const val = fetched[key];
        cache[key] = val;
        resolve(val);
      });
    });
  });
}

function push(cache, key, val) {
  return (new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    cache[key] = val;
    let toSet = {};
    toSet[key] = val;
    chrome.storage.local.set(toSet, resolve);
  }));
}

function useVariables(names, cache, defaults) {
  return Promise
  .all(names.map(vn => pull(cache, vn, defaults[vn])))
  .then(values => values); // “values” is variables’ values
}
```

To use the system, we need a cache object and an object that contains defaults:

```
var globalCache = {};

const globalDefaults = {
  urls : [],
  lastUpdatedTime : 0,
  gapTimeBetweenConsecutiveRequests : 1000,
};
```

And we use specified variables via `useVariable`:

```
useVariables(['urls', 'lastUpdatedTime'], globalCache, globalDefaults)
.then(([urls, lastUpdatedTime]) => {
// …
// code that needs these variables
// …
});
```

Variables are reassigned by calling `push`:

```
push(globalCache, 'lastUpdatedTime', Date.now());
```

**What improvements can be made to the code?**

I wonder if it’s a good idea to change the function `useVariable` to returning an object that has getters and setters. By making this change, variables can be retrieved without repeating their names and can be reassigned without calling `push`.

```
function useVariables(names, cache, defaults) {
  return /* an object that has a getter and a setter for each variable requested */;
}

useVariables(['variable1', 'variable2'], globalCache, globalDefaults)
.then(vars => {
  vars.variable1 = /* new value */;
  vars.variable2 = /* new value */;
});
```

**Is this change a good idea?**

**How can the system be improved?**